# ZPL Page Break / Generating Multiple pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zpl

I am using ZPL for the first time to generate shipping labels.  I am using a ruby-on-rails gem https://github.com/rjocoleman/labelary to ultimately turn the ZPL sting into a pdf.  I want to create multiple pages, incrementing a variable for each page using a loop until enough pages have been created.  Say the ZPL looks like this:

```
^XA

^FX Top section with company logo, name and address.
^CF0,60
^FO50,50^GB100,100,100^FS
^FO75,75^FR^GB100,100,100^FS
^FO88,88^GB50,50,50^FS
^FO220,50^FDInternational Shipping, Inc.^FS
^CF0,40
^FO220,100^FD1000 Shipping Lane^FS
^FO220,135^FDShelbyville TN 38102^FS
^FO220,170^FDUnited States (USA)^FS
^FO50,250^GB700,1,3^FS

^FX Second section with recipient address and permit information.
^CFA,30
^FO50,300^FDJohn Doe^FS
^FO50,340^FD100 Main Street^FS
^FO50,380^FDSpringfield TN 39021^FS
^FO50,420^FDUnited States (USA)^FS
^CFA,15
^FO600,300^GB150,150,3^FS
^FO638,340^FDPermit^FS
^FO638,390^FD123456^FS
^FO50,500^GB700,1,3^FS

^FX Third section with barcode.
^BY5,2,270
^FO175,550^BC^FD1234567890^FS

^FX Fourth section (the two boxes on the bottom).
^FO50,900^GB700,250,3^FS
^FO400,900^GB1,250,3^FS
^CF0,40
^FO100,960^FDShipping Ctr. X34B-1^FS
^FO100,1010^FDREF1 F00B47^FS
^FO100,1060^FDREF2 BL4H8^FS
^CF0,190
^FO485,965^FDCA^FS

^XZ
```

How can I add a page break to the end of the ZPL string, so the loop can create a new identical page after the first one (all in a single zpl string)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you converting to PDF? What are you printing these on? What variable do you want to increment, and how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your pages are truly *identical*, you could just use the `^PQ` command to set the number of copies you want to print (e.g. `^PQ3` to print three copies). This command must appear before the `^XZ` command.

However if your pages aren't identical (maybe you have a sequence number or something), just start a new format by using a new `^XA` command after your first page is done.

Comment: if just `^XA` didn't work for you, that is because you have to close the previous page with `^XZ`. So we can have something like this `^XA^XZ    ^XA^XZ   ^XA^XZ` for 3 pages. Add your code between **XA**-**XZ**s and treat each page with separate coordination.